# How can I get the last part of a songkick URL using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get the last part after the slash from this URL or even just the number using regex:

http://www.songkick.com/artists/2884896-netsky

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Many thanks,
Joe

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: ive tried preg_match("/songkick.*\/(\d+)/i", $url, $result); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a regex pattern to find everything after the last slash - it is ([^//]+)$ . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this is ok for you:

last part:

```
"http://www.songkick.com/artists/2884896-netsky".replace(/.*\//,"")
"2884896-netsky"
```

number:

```
"http://www.songkick.com/artists/2884896-netsky".replace(/.*\//,"").match(/\d+/)
["2884896"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = "http://www.songkick.com/artists/2884896-netsky";
s.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]
```

`[^\/]+` matches one or more characters other than `/`

`$` matches the end of the string

For just the number, try:

```
var value = s.match(/(\d+)[^\/\d]+$/)[1];
value = parseInt(value, 10); // convert it to an Integer
```

`(\d+)` matches any Number and groups it

`[^\/\d]+` matches anything besides Numbers or `/`

[More Info on Javascript Regular Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)